# Validate List of object with Grails Command

Tags: validation, grails, command

I have a 2 command object, SongCommand which include CoupletCommand as List.

```
class SongCommand {

    String title
    List<CoupletCommand> coupletCommandList
    Boolean isChorusRepeat

    static constraints = {
        title blank: false, size:1..129
        coupletCommandList validator: { val, obj ->
            def isValid = true
            obj.each {
                isValid = isValid && it.validate()
            }
            return isValid
        }
    }
}
```

My second Command which included into the SongCommand

```
class CoupletCommand {

    Integer coupletPosition
    String coupletText
    Boolean isChorus

    static constraints = {
        coupletText blank: false, size:20..700
        isChorus nullable: true
    }
}
```

From client side I receive scope of coupletPosition-i, coupletText-i, isChorus-i, where **-i** is some position, so I receive from front-end

coupletText-1

coupletText-2

.....

coupletText-n

Same for two other variable.

My GSP template which generate for each Couplet, can be from 1 to n.

```
<li>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="couplet-${songId}">Couplet:</label>
        <input type="hidden" class="couplet-position" name="coupletPosition-${songId}" value="1">
        <g:textArea name="coupletText-${songId}" class="form-control" rows="5" id="couplet-${songId}"/>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="isChorus-${songId}"/> Is Chorus
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

In the controller I want validate this all and if some of the part is not validate return page with errors and data.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The last sentence.
In the controller I want validate this all and if some of the part is not validate return page with errors and data.